# How to detect with jQuery or JavaScript when HTML5 <audio> element cannot play

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I have a number of audio elements on a page with mp3s from a remote site and sometimes the request to load an mp3 results in a `301 Moved Permanently` response.

When this happens, the player becomes greyed-out but I am unable to detect any error. I tried doing something like this, but the handler is never run:

```
$('audio').on('error', function(){
    // Code to handle the error 
});
```

I've noticed that the audio element's [`networkState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/networkState) is `3` and it's [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState) is `0` when I check these in the console after the page has finished loading, but I can't find an [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) to handle that occurs after these states are reached.

How can I do something (run a function, display a modal, etc) when an mp3 fails to load and the audio element becomes unplayable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution!

```js
window.onload=function(){
  let audioElem=document.querySelectorAll("audio")[0];
  canBePlayed(audioElem);
}
function canBePlayed(audio){
 if(audio.readyState!=0){
  alert("This audio can be played!");
 }else{
  alert("This audio can not be played!");
 }
}
```

```html
<audio src="./audio.ogg" controls>
  Your Browser doesn't support this type of audios
</audio>
```

Comment: I was doing everything on `document.ready` your solution worked because it runs at `window.load`